# Стрельба сверху вниз

Tags: c#, unity3d

Задача состоит теперь сделать стрельбу без таргета.
Сверху вниз.
Вообще не врублюсь никак, что надо то...

```
bull.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.up + new Vector3(-10, -10, 0) * 300);
```

Делал и так:

```
bull.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-10, -10, 0) * 300);
```

Он в одну сторону стреляет нормально, поворачиваю в другую, он под-себя стреляет.
Как это исправить?

Но когда я делаю так:

```
bull.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.down * 300);
```

Он стреляет вниз под углом 90 градусов, при этом когда поворачиваю, он не стреляет под себя.

Как вообще устроен этот `Vector3.down`?

И как сделать такой-же, только с `-10, -10, 0`?

Как мне узнать положение и домножить его к вектору?
или что вообще нужно сделать?

Comment: `(new Vector3(-10, -10, 0)).normalized` вернёт направляющий вектор, который вам так нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос исчерпан, все решил, нужно было просто место спавна пуль повернуть на нужный угол и использовать `Vector3.forward`, при этом брать не позицию главного объекта, как сделал я изначально, а позицию спавна пуль, которую поворачиваем.